# Product with itself is not absolutely convergent $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Show that the product of the series with itself is not absolutely convergent. $$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

I tried looking at Cauchy product series.

$$c_n= a_1b_n+...+a_nb_1\implies c_n= (-1)^n[\sum_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1-r}\sqrt{r}}]\implies c_n\geq(-1)^n.n.\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}.\sqrt{n}}$$

the resultant series $\sum(-1)^n$ is an alternating series. I doubt if I can conclude anything from this as the terms of the series are not non negative. Moreover is the original series is not absolutely convergent, I am not sure if looking at Cauchy product is same as looking at the product itself.

Comment: Consider the modulus of the above $c_n$, is the sequence $|c_n|$ converging to zero?

Comment: But, can I say that absolute convergence of $c_n$ is same as absolute convergence of the direct product of the series. Since $\sum{c_n}= \sum{a_n}.\sum{b_n}$ if both an and bn series are absolutely convergent

Comment: For the simple convergence (of a series) there is a **necessary** condition to have a (converging to) zero sequence of terms. We thus do not need *is same*, but only one direction. So the argument in the question is enough with this small argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$|c_n|=\frac1{\sqrt n}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac1{\sqrt{n-1}}+\cdots+\frac1{\sqrt n}\geqslant\frac n{\sqrt n}=\sqrt n.$$

Comment: Since the original series has negative terms, how can we say that absolute convergence of product of the series with itself is same as absolute convergence of cauchy product. Is it that we are showing Cauchy product is not absolutely convergent therefore, the absolute sum of original product which has to be greater than absolute sum of cauchy product  is also divergent?

Comment: Each $c_n$ is a sum of numbers such that either all of them are positive or all of them are negative. For instance$$c_3=\frac1{\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac1{\sqrt2}+\frac1{\sqrt3}$$and$$c_4=-\frac1{\sqrt4}-\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac1{\sqrt3}-\frac1{\sqrt3}\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac1{\sqrt4}.$$